# Android SPP bluetooth to non Android device

Tags: android, bluetooth, rfcomm

I'm trying to mimic the success of gilead ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2660968/398460)) but so far his code in my app fails.  I've tried multiple UUIDs but nothing works.  When I run `sdptool records [address]` I get:

```
$ sdptool records 00:12:F3:04:80:80
sdptool records 00:12:F3:04:80:80
Service Name: SPP
Service RecHandle: 0x10001
Service Class ID List:
"Serial Port" (0x1101)
Protocol Descriptor List:
"L2CAP" (0x0100)
"RFCOMM" (0x0003)
Channel: 1
Failed to connect to SDP server on 00:12:F3:04:80:80: Connection timed out
```

It shows the device is on channel 1 so I don't understand why the code does not work. I'm running Android 2.1. I cannot access the other device in any way and while debugging tmpsock has all the correct values before `.connect()` is called.

My code

```
public void test(BluetoothDevice d) throws Exception
{
 BluetoothSocket tmpsock = null;
 OutputStream out = null;
 InputStream in = null;
 int port = 1;
 Method m = d.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] { int.class });
 tmpsock = (BluetoothSocket)m.invoke(d, port);
 Log.d("BT", "CONNECTING!!!!");
 tmpsock.connect();
 Log.d("BT", "CONNECTED!");
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [BluetoothDevice createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord%28java.util.UUID%29)

> If you are connecting to a Bluetooth serial board then try using the
>   well-known SPP UUID 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB.