# Send message to LEGO NXT from Android

Tags: android, nxt, lego-mindstorms

I just want to send a message just like string/number into the NXT from my Android. 
But NXT didnt receive the data. I use ROBOT C for NXT program and BluetoothMessage example from the ROBOT C.

First, I try source code for Android from [Bluetooth-connection between Android and Lego Mindstorm NXT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969053/bluetooth-connection-between-android-and-lego-mindstorm-nxt). But didnt work.

Then I download a software from Google Play, NXT Mailbox and it works.

Does anybody has a source code for Android to send message into NXT ?