# Bluetooth remote for an Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, lego-mindstorms

I am new here so I am sorry if my question has already been answered I just could not find an answer!

So I have this first year project in university with a Lego Mindstorm Robot. We are programming the robot on the lego software which is quite easy. We had the robot do a certain function when he receives a message via Bluetooth. The only problem is that the program that we found on the play store wants the user to type in the message and press send but this is not good enough for our project as we need to use our phones as remote controls to turn the robot left and right. So I want to ask you is it too hard to create an android app that consists of 4 buttons each sending a message as follows: left, right, up and down? So far the only programming apart from the lego one I have done is Python and I am only familiar with the basics of it (types, functions, classes, loops, if-statements and the turtle module). From what I have heard Python can't be used to program android so thats why I am asking you guys for help!

Thank you very much in advance! I hope I have made myself clear on what I need to know!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969053/bluetooth-connection-between-android-and-lego-mindstorm-nxt

Comment: It's not too hard if you are a professional mobile application developer like this guy: https://github.com/burf2000/LejosToAndroid

However, "how hard?" is not a good question for the format of StackOverflow. Do some research on how to write an Android app in general, then ask more specific questions if you get stuck on a particular issue.

Comment: Thank you both for the answers! They were both helpful!