# Connect Android to Health Device via bluetooth

Tags: android, exception, bluetooth, mac-address

Well im desperately trying to connect my android app to a blood pressure device. I've realized that the amount of examples of this are few . Right now I am stuck at the connection point. It keeps failing with

```
 12-21 18:00:38.796: E/Connection Failed(2207): java.io.IOException: Service discovery failed
```

Im following the steps :

1 - getting the default adapter

```
mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
```

2 - getting the device

```
mBluetoothDevice = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(DEVICE_MAC_ADD);
```

3- creating a socket

```
mBtSocket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                                UUID);
```

4 - Canceling discovery and connect to device

```
mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

mBtSocket.connect();
```

It fails on the connect method with the exception above. Well im kind of lost trying to know why this happens . Im using the UUID 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB as referenced in other threads. The bluetooth permissions on the manifest are correct. Can someone give me a little help?

Thank you,
Pedro Ferreira

Comment: have you seen this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660968/how-to-prevent-android-bluetooth-rfcomm-connection-from-dying-immediately-after

Answer (score 2):

If your blood pressure device is compatible with HDP profile, then you can use the health profile supported in android 4.0 to do this job.

Take a look:
[BluetoothHDP Demo](http://java.llp2.dcc.ufmg.br/apiminer/docs/resources/samples/BluetoothHDP/index.html)