# Trouble connecting Android app to OS X through bluetooth Serial Port Profile

Tags: android, macos, bluetooth, serial-port, osx-lion

I'm attempting to connect to a Bluetooth port on my MacBook Pro (OS X v10.8 "Mountain Lion") from an android app (Device Version 2.2 "Froyo").

Starting with the BluetoothChat example, I removed the server-side code (only need client), and updated for API Level 8 compatibility.  I can pair fine, but then I receive an `IOException: Connection Refused` error on `bluetoothSocket.connect()`.

I am using the standard Serial Port Profile UUID `00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb`, and I verified that it was supported using reflection, as show in
[The Missing Manual: Android Bluetooth RFCOMM](http://wiresareobsolete.com/wordpress/2010/11/android-bluetooth-rfcomm/)

After doing some research [here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660968) and on the [Google Code Forums](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5427)
I tried using reflection to get a socket, which gives me the same result.

I've tried playing around with the Bluetooth port settings in OS X, but I can't find any documentation on them, and I have no idea what options I should set.

I have checked "Discoverable" in the main preferences panel:
[image: Bluetooth Preferences]

I found the Serial Ports Menu, which is hidden by default.  First you have to click options->Show More Info.  Then Click options again, and you should see "Edit Serial Port...".  I have no idea what to set here:
[image: Edit Serial Ports Menu]

There are more serial port settings in the Advanced pane:
[image: Bluetooth Advanced Preferences]

Anyone have any experience with this, or know what these options mean?

**Edit**
I'm running [Serial Communication in OSX Terminal](http://www.tigoe.net/pcomp/resources/archives/avr/000749.shtml) on all ports returned by `ls /dev/tty.*`.  As shown in the link, I basically use `screen /dev/tty.<port name> <datarate>`
I've been using 9600 for the datarate, although I don't know if it matters.

Comment: So what is running on your Mac to talk to the BT Chat app?

Comment: @MorrisonChang Updated the question to address your comment.