# which type about how to user android bluetooth sockect connection is better

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, connection

type one:

```
Method m = btDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] { int.class });

btSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(btDevice, 1);

btSocket.connect();
```

type two:

```
private final UUID SPP_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
btSocket = btDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(SPP_UUID);
btSocket.connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the second solution is better because it implements better error-handling internally.

Source:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18582044/3250699